# Can't build java project with ant

Tags: java, ant, build, javac

I have a java project with structure like this :

```
src/
bin/
lib/
build.xml
```

I am building it with ant in Window, but I get this error:

```
build:

...

[javac] javac: invalid flag: -g:${debuglevel}
[javac] Usage: javac < options > < source files>
[javac] use -help for a list of possible options

BUILD FAILED
```

Here is my environment variables :

```
ANT_HOME = c:\programs\WinAnt    
JAVA_HOME = c:\programs\java\jdk1.7.0_25
PATH = c:\programs\WinAnt\bin
```

Should the `PATH` variable be pointing to the JDK directory? But if I do so the "ant" command won't be recognized. I can't figure out what's causing this problem, does anyone have any idea of a possible solution?

Comment: It sounds like your `debuglevel` property is not set, and the build file requires it.  What happens if you execute `ant -Ddebuglevel=source`?

Comment: now it says BUILD SUCCESSFUL :D you found the problem. I wouldn't figure it out by myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Copied from comment above)

It sounds like your `debuglevel` property is not set, and the build file requires it.

Apparently everything works fine if you define the `debuglevel` property on the command line like so:

```
ant -Ddebuglevel=source
```

You could also modify your `build.xml` file to include something like:

```
<property name="debuglevel" value="source"/>
```

Or alternatively:

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

where `build.properties` contains something like:

```
debuglevel=source
```

---

FWIW, I suspect anything that is valid for the `-g:` option to `javac` would work here, depending on how much debug information you need.  The valid options for your compiler can probably be found by issuing the command `javac -help` on the command line.  For me, with Oracle JDK 1.7.0, the valid options are any combination of `lines,vars,source`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with a slight difference. Error that I was getting was:

```
[javac] javac: invalid flag: \customization\ejb\src
[javac] Usage: javac < options > < source files>
[javac] use -help for a list of possible options

BUILD FAILED
```

My source folder was: `my customization\ejb\src`
The problematic part here was the space in my folder name. I renamed my folder to `customization` and updated **build.properties** accordingly.
After that it started building my application normally.

Posting it here might help some one else.